# Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'

Tags: asp.net-identity

I have an MVC5 application using Entity Framework 6.1 and Asp.Net Identity 2 and have data migrations enabled. I have used sample code from other answers on StackExchange to seed the Role and User tables. My application data context is based on IdentityDbContext. 
On issuing an update-database command, my database is created and populated with the following tables:

[image: List of tables from SQL Server Object Explorer]

My app launches OK, but when I try to log in using the seeded user (or any user for that matter), I get the following error:
[image: Screen shot of error message]

How can I get SignInManager to reference the IdentityUsers table instead of AspNetUsers?

Answer (score 3):

You can set custom names in OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(mb);

    mb.Entity<User>().ToTable("IdentityUsers");
   ...
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of <User>? I have also tried Entity<AspNetUsers>, as in the missing object, but both show an error that "The type or namespace name 'User/AspNetUser' cannot be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)'

Comment: User should be entity name generated from Identity 2.0 CodeFirst

Comment: I now have the project building OK with the line `modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("IdentityUsers");` but when I run update-database in PackageManagerConsole I get this error: `One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

IdentityUser_Logins_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'IdentityUser_Logins_Target' in relationship 'IdentityUser_Logins'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'`